# How to tell SQL Server Export Wizard to also create indexes of new table in destination?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, export

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a source database and a destination database. 
In source database I have a table named **rule_attribute** which have 2 indexes. 
This table does not exist in destination database.

I ran the SQL Server Export Wizard to copy this table from source database to destination database.

The wizard ran successfully and the table was copied to destination database along with data. But the 2 indexes on this table were not created.

Is there any reason why indexes were not created?

Is there any setting which allows to create indexes as part of wizard?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Import/Export wizard doesn't allow copying indexes, but if you use the `Database Scripting` tool it will allow you to add indexes in the scripts.

[image]

Comment: I guess I have to use `Generate Scripts` option and then do the data insert manually instead of `Export Data` option?

Comment: @ChumboChappati No, consider choosing the `Schema and data` for `types of data to script` as highlighted by M.Ali in the image.

Comment: @ChumboChappati By the way, voting for your accepted answer is a good habit ;)